# Heston & Nandi GARCH model, parameters estimation from option data

Tags: options, option-pricing, garch, heston

I wonder if anybody has code for the HN-GARCH model where the parameters is NOT estimated with maximum likelihood and instead estimated by looking at the option data where an loss function is chosen and is minimized, so the parameters in the model deliver a call price that is close as possible to the market price? Similar approach is common to use to estimate the parameters in the Heston stochastic volatility model.